# Can I use a wildcard on the database value rather than the variable I'm comparing against?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically is there a way I can do this:

```
Select * from TABLE WHERE "%nickName%" LIKE "longName"
```

I don't want to break the longName into substrings of the individual words and compare each one, because this is for companies, so if I say:

```
WHERE 'nickName' LIKE "%word1%"
or    'nickName' LIKE "%word2%"
```

When there is an "LLC" in the long name it would return all companies in database with an LLC in the name.

Any ideas? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Basically, no. You can't use wildcards in a column name, period.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Does this do what you want?

```
where nickName regexp replace(longname, ' ', '|')
```

If `longname` is "abc def ghi", then this will turn it into "abc|def|ghi", which is the regular expression for finding any of those three words.

Comment: That's a really good expression - but I think it wills still produce the problems of if longName="Smith Electronics LLC" it will return "Dawson MicroComputers LLC" and "Allen Development LLC" but I only want it to return things like "Smith" or "Smith Electronics"

Comment: @codezilla . . . That would appear to be what you are asking for.